# Importance of work experience for MS in physics

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, physics

I am currently enrolled in a 3-year Physics Hons. programme. I plan to pursue physics in my masters as well but from the UK or Germany(Right now, I am studying in India). I am doing a lot of freelance software work like web development and hackathons. I was wondering if they will contribute positively to my masters application or be seen as a distraction by foreign universities? Will my experience in coding and software add to my application or take away from it?

Comment: Also, how much is the value of a CV with a lot of work in software when applying for masters?

Comment: (I'm in the US, so only commenting.) If you emphasize how your computational experience can help support scientists with computational research projects (i.e. when you explain what groups you are interested in working with), that could be seen as a positive. If it's just something you did, maybe less so.

Comment: Web development might not be as directly related to the work of a physicist as some other applications.  But in general, I'd think this would be viewed as an asset.